# Unable to append a div to a div in Google Calendar's DOM

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api, appendchild

When in Week View, in `https://calendar.google.com/*`'s DOM there is the div below:

`<div role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" jsname="RjPD4e" aria-labelledby="tsc-0" data-column-index="0" data-datekey="27390" data-principal-ids="cnlsYW5kQHN0YWNrYml0LmNvbQ" class="YvjgZe"></div>`

In the Content Scripts file in my manifest v3 chrome extension, the expected behavior of the code snippet below is to select the `mainDiv` above and append `newDiv` to it.

```
const mainDiv = document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby="tsc-0"]');

const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = 'Hello World';

mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
console.log('mainDiv', mainDiv);
```

The behavior occuring is that `mainDiv` *is* selected, but the `newDiv` is *not* appended.

Why and how can I append a div to `mainDiv`?

Comment: mainDiv appears in DOM after your content script runs, so use MutationObserver to wait for it.